# bidirectional binding in C# like Javafx

Tags: c#, .net, javafx

In Javafx for bidirectional binding a combobox selected item to an object property(attribute) simply I used :

```
linkComboBox.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(linkBean.linkTypeProperty());
```

Now I want to do this action in C# .net (windows form) can I do that as simple as javafx?

I have read questions about c# binding to object property, the problem is combo box data source must be a class while in my question combobox items are static and I just want to bidirectional bind selected item to a property of an object.

Comment: @stuartd my question is different.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question answers this one.

Comment: @Amy its bidirectional binding? when combobox is loaded does it use object property to choose item which was selected before?

Comment: that question doesn't refer to bidirectional binding

Comment: @N_93 your question asks _"binding a combobox selected item to an object property"_ - the linked question is titled _"Binding a ComboBox SelectedItem to an Object Property"_ - and the question doesn't need to refer to "bidirectional binding" as that's what a DataBinding is.

Comment: @stuatrd consider my question title and the javafx code please.

Comment: We have, and have rejected this question as a duplicate of the marked question.  Please take the time to understand it and apply it to your own problem.  It *does* address this question.